# Strange characters in Eclipse IDE Project Explorer window

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I tried `Eclipse IDE` for Enterprise Java Developers versions `2019-03` and `2020-06`.

However, something occurs when projects are imported using `Maven` or `Gradle`. There are some strange characters in the project explorer window.

This is a screen shot of the project explorer:

[image]

Can anyone tell me what's happening?

Comment: can you provide the project in rar/jar form, we will try to recreate the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that your imported project is English?

Comment: [This thread](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/1104362/1829403/#msg_1829403) advises to disable the _Use mixed fonts and colors for labels_ option (_Window > Preferences > General > Appearance_); does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the Use mixed fonts and colors for labels option (Window > Preferences > General > Appearance) suggestion worked.  Thank you.